# How to install MySQL 5.7.18 in Ubuntu machine?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04, mysql5

I need to install MySQL 5.7.18 in an Ubuntu machine, the apt repo and official MySQL site shows only the version 5.7.24

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you cannot use a different version?

Comment: @DanielB Yes... I want exactly 5.7.18 for testing purpose

Comment: You can always install MySQL from source then.